# Is this type of integration supported by Power Automate (Power automate calls local API then Power automate calls SharePoint online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, flow, power-automate

We have a local API that is not exposed to the internet.

So my question is, can we call this API using Power Automate and then send the API result to SharePoint online? or to be able to call an API from Power Automate we need to expose the API to the internet? or Power automate does allow us to call local APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **on-premises data gateway** to connect to APIs hosted within your internal network.

Check below articles for more information:

1. [What is an on-premises data gateway?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/gateway-reference)
2. [Connect to custom on-premises APIs using data gateway](https://flow.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/on-premise-apis/)